# How to change position of an object in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, position, location

I'm trying to add a dynamic map to my site but it is getting cut off by the navbar and getting cut off by the bottom of the page. I tried using a container but the navbar was still cutting it off and it looked a lot worse. Heres the site: http://whynotmine.net/DynMap.html#

And here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DynamicMap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width+device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head> 

    <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class = "container">

            <a href = "http://whynotmine.net" class = "navbar-brand">WhyNotMine</a>

            <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li><a href = "http://whynotmine.net">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "http://whynotmine.net/DynMap.html#">DynMap</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "http://whynotmine.net/Polls.html#">Polls</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "http://whynotmine.net/Donations.html#">Donations</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "http://whynotmine.net/About.html#">About</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

        <iframe src="http://107.167.82.34:8123" width="100%" height="1000">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
```

Comment: Moar code. Please give us more code to work with.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast done. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Easy one for the top navbar, this behaviour is explained in the BS3 Documentation http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top.

Essentially you want to add...

```
body {
padding: 70px;
}
```

That will sort out the problems for the top navbar, unfortunately I don't really understand where you're coming from where it's getting cut off at the bottom of the page? I see no real problem here apart from the navbar and a heap load of Errors.

I'd focus sorting out the errors and that should either sort your problems or slim down what is causing your problems.